# How can I take the SUM of an alias field based on a condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, scope, subquery, alias

I am new to MySQL and SQL in general, I was able to get part of my query to work as intended but I'm not confident nor sure how to precisely turn my query into a subquery for my goals.

Context regarding the DB:
I am helping design an app for my college's conference where they want the judges to be able to score a poster that is owned by a presenter(s) and a presenter can have several posters. There are five tables.

```
Judge
Poster
Presenter
Owns
Scores
```

Context regarding the query:
the query below outputs the presenter's name and the sum of that particular record's values from the score table

```
    SELECT
    presenter.presenter_name,
    (visual + clarity + thoroughness
     + breadth + depth + quality
     + discussion + understanding + overall)
    AS rec_tot
    FROM scores
    INNER JOIN judge ON judge.judge_id = scores.judge_ID
    INNER JOIN poster ON poster.poster_ID = scores.poster_ID
    INNER JOIN owns ON poster.poster_ID = owns.poster_ID
    INNER JOIN presenter ON presenter.presenter_ID = owns.presenter_ID
    ORDER BY presenter.academic_level, presenter.area_of_study,
    presenter.category;
```

Which will output the following:

```
presenter_name | rec_tot
------------------------
nameOne        | 17
nameTwo        | 27
nameTwo        | 18
nameTwo        | 16
nameThree      | 9
```

I want to take this query and output the SUM(rec_tot) group by presenter_name so something like:

```
presenter_name | rec_tot
------------------------
nameOne        | 17
nameTwo        | 61
nameThree      | 9
```

Below is my attempt at addressing the issue:

```
    SELECT a.*, SUM(rec_tot) AS total
    FROM (SELECT (visual + clarity + thoroughness + breadth
                 + depth + quality + discussion
                 + understanding + overall) AS rec_tot
    FROM scores
    INNER JOIN judge ON judge.judge_id = scores.judge_ID
    INNER JOIN poster ON poster.poster_ID = scores.poster_ID
    INNER JOIN owns ON poster.poster_ID = owns.poster_ID
    INNER JOIN presenter ON presenter.presenter_ID = 
    owns.presenter_ID
    ORDER BY presenter.academic_level, presenter.area_of_study, 
    presenter.category
    ) AS a;
```

However, this just gives me the sum of all the entries as:

```
rec_tot | total
----------------
  27    |  87
```

But every time I try and reference the table made in the subquery with a GROUP BY presenter.presenter_name I get 'ERROR: 1054. Unknown column "presenter.presenter_ID" in "GROUP BY"'. So I figured a parent query couldn't access a child query, which leads me to try and use the FROM clause from the child on the parent query together, however, then the total is outputted as 435 which is 5x87... so that's confusing.

Also, removing the alias 'a' I get the error 'ERROR: 1284. Every derived table must have its own alias'

In short, I'm very confused about the scope of alias, subqueries and how to properly implement them.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it, you only nee to add the group by:

```
select a.presenter_name,sum(a.rec_tot)
from 
(SELECT
    presenter.presenter_name as presenter_name,
    (visual + clarity + thoroughness
     + breadth + depth + quality
     + discussion + understanding + overall)
    AS rec_tot
    FROM scores
    INNER JOIN judge ON judge.judge_id = scores.judge_ID
    INNER JOIN poster ON poster.poster_ID = scores.poster_ID
    INNER JOIN owns ON poster.poster_ID = owns.poster_ID
    INNER JOIN presenter ON presenter.presenter_ID = owns.presenter_ID
    ORDER BY presenter.academic_level, presenter.area_of_study,
    presenter.category) a
group by a.presenter_name
```

Comment: I figured I was close but I'm still getting the 1054 error, it's now not recognizing a.rec_total in the field list

Comment: Sorry to double post but my edit wasn't going through, however, I found the issue; I was using rec_tot and you had a.rec_total being passed. Again, thank you so much for the help!

Comment: If my answer solved your issue , could yo upvote it and accept it?